# Algorithm to find length of a segment that connects center of two rectangles

Tags: algorithm, line, center, segment

Ok, here is the story : I found this problem in one of the pizza boxes a few weeks ago. It said if you can solve this before you could finish the pizza, you would get hired at tripadviser. Though I am not looking to get hired, this problem got my eyes and spoiled my focus on pizza and dinner. I worked out something but with some assumptions. Here is the question :

Assume we know P,Q  R and S. There is the line connecting centers of each rectangle. We need to find out points C and D. I am not sure if there is some other variable that we should know to solve this.
[image]

**EDIT**

Looking for a programmatic or psudo-code explanation- no need to move to maxthexchange.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: think this one should go on [math exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looking for a programmatic than a math like explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do step-by-step:

1. Compute A = (P + Q) / 2 and B = R + S / 2 (component-by-component)
2. An equation for the line between A and B is `L(t) = t * A + (1 - t) * (B - A)`. Just solve
   this linear equation for a `t*` such that `L(t*).y = Q.y` to get `C = L(t*)`. Do a similar thing with L(t).y = R.y to get D.

You can also use the values of `t*` that you get when solving for C and D to determine pathological cases like overlapping rectangles.

Comment: +1 I agree this is much simpler and straight-forward than what I suggested. I'll leave my answer up as it is valid, but this is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to find the points `C` and `D` to find the distance.

I assume you already know the coordinates of the rectangle. It's trivial to compute the coordinates of the center points and the lenghts of the edges.

Now, imagine a vertical line passing through `A` and a horizontal line passing through `B`. They intersect at a point, call it `X`. Also, imagine a vertical line passing through C and call its intersection point with the top edge of rectangle `RS` - `C'`.

You can trivially compute the length of `AX`. But the length of `AX` is half the height of `RS` + half the height of `PQ` (both of which you know) + the length of `CC'`.

So now you know the length of `CC'` (call it `x`).

You can also compute the angle (call it `n`) that `AB` makes with `CC'` from `A` and B's coordinates, since you know `CC'` is vertical.

Ergo, the length of the segment CD is `x * cos(n)`.